# MySQL - Add Foreign key Error

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a foreignkey to a column but I get following error:

> (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

=> **What I checked** was, whether the columns have some different types but they've the same.

=> So, rights from tbl_user is the foreignkey and should reference to rights_id from tbl_userrights

=> Code, that I used:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RIGHTS_ID FOREIGN KEY (rights) REFERENCES rights_id(id);
```

**tbl_user:**

```
#   Name    Typ     Kollation   Attribute   Null    Standard    Extra
1   id      int(11)                         No                  AUTO_INCREMENT

2   rights  int(11)                         No
```

**tbl_userrights:**

```
 #  Name        Typ     Kollation   Attribute   Null    Standard    Extra
1   rights_id   int(11)                         No                  AUTO_INCREMENT

2   rights      varchar(50)                     No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `FOREIGN KEY` definition is not entirely correct. The pattern is:

```
FOREIGN KEY (referencing_columns) REFERENCES referenced_table (referenced_columns)
```

So where you have `REFERENCES rights_id(id)`, you should actually be using

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_user
  ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RIGHTS_ID 
  FOREIGN KEY (rights) REFERENCES tbl_userrights (rights_id)
```

See [the `FOREIGN KEY` documentation syntax reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) for full details on syntax options.

You were right to check that the data types match, and that is a common error (also common are attempting to create the FK before the referenced table exists or has an index on the referenced column), but this time it was just down to syntax.

Comment: It worked. Wow you did answer pretty fast. Thank you.. I'm new to MySQL, didn't know, that I had to enter the table, I want to reference from..

Answer (score 0):

The column(s) referred to by a foreign key constraint should be either unique keys or primary keys.  First, your reference is not quite correct:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RIGHTS_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (rights) REFERENCES rights_id(id);
------------------------------------^
```

should be:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_user ADD CONSTRAINT FK_RIGHTS_ID
    FOREIGN KEY (rights) REFERENCES tbl_userrights(rights_id);
```

(although I think the column should be called `rights_id` in both tables to avoid confusion.)

Second, you need to `tbl_userrights(rights_id)` as the primary key of the table, in addition to being auto-incremented.

Comment: Thanks for your answer too, the problem is solved but you've quite the same answer as @Michael Berkowski. Thank you!